Submenu with buttons opens again and again
I have a problem. I have created a button and when I press it a submenu should appear if available showUnderDialog with further buttons that can be pressed.
The following problem is that when I press the button, the submenu appears and I can press the buttons, BUT it reappears after a few seconds. So the submenu does not close properly or disappears.
How can I make the submenu really close and not reappear after the button has been pressed?
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import '../utils/definitions.dart';
import 'icons.dart';
import '../model/label.dart';

class LabelButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final Label? label;
  final VoidStringCallback? process;

  LabelButton({required this.label, required this.process, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LabelButton> createState() => _LabelButtonState();

  const LabelButton._(this.label, this.process, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  static LabelButton createBlank() {
    return const LabelButton._(null, null);
  }
}

class _LabelButtonState extends State<LabelButton> {
  bool _hasBeenPressed = false;
  bool _isShowingDialog = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.label != null) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          child: Material(
            child: InkWell(
              highlightColor: const Color(0xFF00D3F8).withOpacity(0.3),
              splashColor: const Color(0xFFB20DD3).withOpacity(0.3),
              onTap: () async {
                if (!_hasBeenPressed && !_isShowingDialog) {
                  setState(() {
                    _hasBeenPressed = true;
                    _isShowingDialog = true;
                  });

                  String? selectedUnder;
                  if (widget.label!.under != null && widget.label!.under!.isNotEmpty) {
                    selectedUnder = await showUnderDialog(context, widget.label!.under!);
                  }

                  List<String>? selectedUnderList = selectedUnder != null ? [selectedUnder] : null;
                  widget.process!(
                    widget.label!.identifier,
                    widget.label!.category,
                    widget.label!.modus,
                    widget.label!.id,
                    selectedUnderList,
                  );

                  HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
                  _isShowingDialog = false;
                  // Nach einer kurzen Verzögerung den Zustand zurücksetzen
                  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                    if (mounted) {
                      setState(() {
                        _hasBeenPressed = false;
                        _isShowingDialog = false; // Dialogstatus zurücksetzen
                      });
                    }
                  });
                }
              },
              child: Ink(
                width: 100,
                height: 133,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: getColor(),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    getIcon(),
                    Text(
                      widget.label!.category,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF696969),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Text(
                        widget.label!.identifier,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }

  Color getColor() {
    if (_hasBeenPressed) {
      switch (widget.label!.modus) {
        case "driving":
          return colorDrivingClicked;
        case "parking":
          return colorParkingClicked;
        default:
          return colorWeatherClicked;
      }
    } else {
      switch (widget.label!.modus) {
        case "driving":
          return colorDriving;
        case "parking":
          return colorParking;
        default:
          return colorWeather;
      }
    }
  }

  Icon getIcon() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.ac_unit,
      size: 80,
      color: _hasBeenPressed ? const Color(0xFFB6B6B6) : const Color(0xFFE9E9E9),
    );
  }

  Future<String?> showUnderDialog(BuildContext context, List<String> underOptions) async {
    return await showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Select an option'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: underOptions.map((option) {
              return ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(option);
                },
                child: Text(option),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


IT's hard to debug like this. Can you [edit] your question to include the VoidStringCallback and Label?

It's not possible to debug it without the missing widgets/functions so my guess is that it's happening because of await Future.delayed which rebuilds the widget after 2 second when setState is called.

Remove the Future.delayed call and reset the state immediately after the dialog is dismissed. This ensures the submenu won't reappear unexpectedly.
Replace:
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
  if (mounted) {
    setState(() {
      _hasBeenPressed = false;
      _isShowingDialog = false;
    });
  }
});

With:
setState(() {
  _hasBeenPressed = false;
  _isShowingDialog = false;
});


Your call to await Future.delayed will call setState after 2 seconds. This will cause a rebuild of the whole widget and cause onTap to be called again, recreating the dialog.
Since you are already calling await on showUnderDialog, your code will wait until you get a return value from the dialog, so you can remove the Future.delayed call

By using Navigator.of(context).pop(), you can close the dialog and removing it from the widget tree,
      onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); // <--- Change here
                return option; // Return the selected option
              },
              child: Text(option),


If I want return option, I got the following error message: The return type 'String' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context. And with Navigator.of(context).pop(); it does not work.

And what is the difference between Navigator.of(context).pop(); and Navigator.of(context).pop(option); ?
